# Fail to connect php mysql with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem to connect PHP with MySQL this is my connexion file:

```
    <?php
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ecom;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
     }

    ?>
```

it show's me this error:

> could not find driver

I'm using xampp btw as a server 3.2.4 last version

Comment: DO NOT make any decorations in your DSN. Why there is a line break?

Comment: FYI, to solve all the future problems: [how to **properly** connect with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql)